# Check if specific .Accdb file running in MSACESS process

Tags: ms-access, process

I have the following code in Visual Studio that check to see if a MS ACCESS database is open or not.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim psList() As Process
    Try
        psList = Process.GetProcesses()

        For Each p As Process In psList
            If InStr(p.ProcessName, "access", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Or InStr(p.ProcessName, "myAccessDbFile_fe", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                MsgBox(p.Id.ToString() + " " + p.ProcessName)
            End If
        Next p

    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But the problem is that this code tell me that MSACCESS is a process that is running on the computer but it does not tell me if my specific ms access db file open.
i.e. myAccessDbFile_fe

Can someone help by tell me the syntax. I need to check if my specific file has been loaded with the MSACCESS application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag language you used correctly. And you need to check command line parameters for MSACCESS process, accdb name will be there.

Comment: The platform is not relevant, the language is. It looks like VB.Net, so add this tag.

Comment: How about getting window caption /title name?

Comment: Here is a VBA solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39847902/3820271

Answer (score 0):

```
if inStr( Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.FileName,".Accdb") <> -1 then

end if
```